# At the time of Peter's confession, who knew that Jesus was Messiah?

Tags: gospels, elijah, messianic-secret

In the synoptic gospels, Peter acknowledges that Jesus is the Messiah.

> Matthew 16:15-17 (NASB) He said to them, “But who do you say that I am?” Simon Peter answered, “You are the Christ, the Son of the living God.” And Jesus said to him, “Blessed are you, Simon Barjona, because flesh and blood did not reveal this to you, but My Father who is in heaven.
>
> Mark 8:27–30 (NASB) Jesus went out, along with His disciples, to the villages of Caesarea Philippi; and on the way He questioned His disciples, saying to them, “Who do people say that I am?” They told Him, saying, “John the Baptist; and others say Elijah; but others, one of the prophets.” And He continued by questioning them, “But who do you say that I am?” Peter *answered and *said to Him, “You are the Christ.” And He warned them to tell no one about Him.
>
> Luke 9:18–21 And it happened that while He was praying alone, the disciples were with Him, and He questioned them, saying, “Who do the people say that I am?” They answered and said, “John the Baptist, and others say Elijah; but others, that one of the prophets of old has risen again.” And He said to them, “But who do you say that I am?” And Peter answered and said, “The Christ of God.” But He warned them and instructed them not to tell this to anyone,

It was apparently a secret, and Jesus instructed his disciples not to tell anyone. According to the chronology given by the synoptic gospels, other than those present at that moment, who was in on the secret?

Answer (score 1):

Other than the Apostles who were present and depending on one's interpretation of what **"who"** stands for, it seems that at least the **demons** knew that Jesus was the Messiah.

> Moreover, demons came out of many people, shouting, "You are the Son of God!" But he rebuked them and would not allow them to speak, because **they knew he was the Messiah.** - [Luke 4:41](http://biblehub.com/luke/4-41.htm)

It would also be believed by many that **Mary** would have known that her Son was the Messiah also.

> 26And in the sixth month the angel Gabriel was sent from God unto a city of Galilee, named Nazareth, 27 To a virgin espoused to a man whose name was Joseph, of the house of David; and the virgin's name was Mary. 28 And the angel came in unto her, and said, Hail, thou that art highly favoured, the Lord is with thee: blessed art thou among women. 29 And when she saw him, she was troubled at his saying, and cast in her mind what manner of salutation this should be. 30 And the angel said unto her, Fear not, Mary: for thou hast found favour with God. 31 And, behold, thou shalt conceive in thy womb, and bring forth a son, and shalt call his name JESUS. 32 He shall be great, and shall be called the Son of the Highest: and the Lord God shall give unto him the throne of his father David: 33 And he shall reign over the house of Jacob for ever; and of his kingdom there shall be no end. 34 Then said Mary unto the angel, How shall this be, seeing I know not a man? 35 And the angel answered and said unto her, The Holy Ghost shall come upon thee, and the power of the Highest shall overshadow thee: **therefore also that holy thing which shall be born of thee shall be called the Son of God.** -  [Luke 1: 26-37.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annunciation)

Answer (score 0):

I notice that, in a way, you limit your question to the synoptic gospels, but a biblical basis must include John's Gospel unless *John* is to be regarded as 'different' or inaccurate. In John's Gospel, Andrew and Peter knew this from the very beginning:

> John 1:40-41: One of the two which heard John speak, and followed him, was Andrew, Simon Peter's brother. He first findeth his own brother Simon, and saith unto him, **We have found the Messias**, which is, being interpreted, **the Christ**.

In the synoptic gospels, the demons knew that Jesus was the Messiah, Son of God.

Comment: Andrew's question makes note that "Jesus went out, along with His disciples, to the villages of Caesarea Philippi...", so I guess  that the Apostles Andrew and John were present at Peter's confession.

Comment: (-1) I intentionally limited the questions to the synoptics because I am aware of that verse.